# Get index for argmin of 2d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array of distances:

```
a = np.array([[2.0, 12.1, 99.2], 
              [1.0, 1.1, 1.2], 
              [1.04, 1.05, 1.5], 
              [4.1, 4.2, 0.2], 
              [10.0, 11.0, 12.0], 
              [3.9, 4.9, 4.99] 
             ])
```

I need a function that assesses each row and returns the column index for the column that has the smallest value. Of course, this can be done trivially by doing:

```
np.argmin(a, axis=1)
```

which yields:

```
[0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0]
```

However, I have a few constraints:

1. The argmin evaluation should only consider distances below a value of 5.0. If none of the distances within a row are below 5.0 then return '-1' as the index
2. The list of indices returned for all rows need to be unique (i.e. if two or more rows end up with the same column index then the row with the smaller distance to the given column index is given priority and all other rows must return a different column index). I'm guessing that this will make the problem an iterative one since if one of the rows gets bumped then it could subsequently clash with another row with the same column index.
3. Any unassigned rows should return '-1'

Thus, the final output should look like:

```
[-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -1]
```

One starting point would be to:

1. perform an argsort
2. assign unique column indices to rows
3. remove assigned column indices from each row
4. resolve tie-breaks
5. repeat step 2-4 until either all column indices are assigned

Is there a straightforward way to accomplish this in Python?

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: How is the first element of expected o/p a `nan`, given that first row has `2.0` in it which is lesser than `5.0`? Or do you mean all elements in a row must be lesser than `5.0`?

Comment: I disagree with your new expected output. In row  `3`, column `2` is smallest (`0.2`), but you have that `np.argmin(a, 1)` is `1`, even without your constraints. For the new `a`, `np.argmin(a, 1)` gives `array([0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0])`, so the final output should be `array([-1,  0, -1,  2, -1, -1])`, I think.

Comment: @Divakar, OP is only looking for _close_ rows, with at least one distance under 5: "If none of the distances within a row are below 5.0 then return `-1` as the index", so it's the row with `[10.0, 11.0, 12.0]` that should be `-1` (previously `nan`).

Comment: @askewchan: You're right. I fixed the mistake for the np.argmin(a, 1) results. Also, thanks for clarifying to Divakar.

Comment: @slaw, I think you also need to fix the expected final output. As I understand your problem statement, your final output cannot differ from the argmin output except that some values have been set to `-1`. As shown, the value for row `2` changes from `0` to `1`.

Comment: @askewchan To the contrary, the final output can/should differ from argmin if another row has a shorter distance. In the example, 5 out of 6 rows have col `0` as their argmin value but row `1` is assigned to col `0` since it has the smallest distance (1.0). Once a column has been assigned to a row then that column cannot be reassigned. However, all other rows that that had a final output of col `0` should then be updated to the column of next shortest distance (not to -1) while still being below 5.0 (otherwise, set to -1) and so forth. So, the next closest column for row `2` is now col `1`.

Comment: Oh, I completely misunderstood the question, very sorry. Thanks for the clarification! I will attempt to fix my solution, but if not I'll just delete it. Stand by.

Comment: @askewchan No worries! I appreciate your help and look forward to your updated answer as I know we're getting close. That's why I said `I'm guessing that this will make the problem an iterative one` in the second constraint.

Answer (score 0):

This loops over the number of columns, which I assume is smaller than the number of rows:

```
def find_smallest(a):
    i = np.argmin(a, 1)
    amin = a[np.arange(len(a)), i] # faster than a.min(1)?
    toobig = amin >=5
    i[toobig] = -1
    for u, c in zip(*np.unique(i, return_counts=True)):
        #u, c are the unique values and number of occurrences in `i`
        if c < 2:
            # no repeats of this index
            continue
        mask = i==u # the values in i that match u, which has repeats
        notclosest = np.where(mask)[0].tolist() # indices of the repeats
        notclosest.pop(np.argmin(amin[mask])) # the smallest a value is not a 'repeat', remove it from the list
        i[notclosest] = -1 # and mark all the repeats as -1
    return i
```

Note, I've used `-1` instead of `np.nan` since an index array is `int`. Any reduction in the boolean indexing would help. I wanted to use one of the optional additional outputs from `np.unique(i)` but couldn't.

Comment: Can you please provide a little more detail as to what is happening in the for loop?

Comment: It looks like your solution cannot handle `a = np.array([[2.0, 12.1, 99.2],
              [1.0, 1.1, 1.2],
              [1.04, 1.05, 1.5],
              [4.1, 4.2, 0.2],
              [10.0, 11.0, 12.0],
              [3.9, 4.9, 4.99]
             ])` In particular, the column index assigned to the third row will be wrong when applying your method

Comment: @slaw Edit your question with this sample data and tell us the expected output as this sample would test out those constraints in a better way?

Comment: I've updated the question with this sample data and expected output

Comment: @slaw, I added commentary and a small fix.